# Smartgwt collapse / expand all listgrid records

Tags: java, smartgwt

I have a listgrid like this:
http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#grid_nested_form

It appears a form when I click expand button.

Is there some way to expand only one element? In another words, fire collapse event of all records of my listgrid except the one I have selected.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `setCanExpandMultipleRecords` method to achieve that sort of spring-back effect.

```
grid.setCanExpandMultipleRecords(false);
```